# Estimating a sum with a fractional part

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is it possible to pick up the value $\log^2 x<y<x$ to get this expressions simultaneously
$$\sum_{d\leq y}\left \{ \frac{x}{d} \right \}\leqslant \frac{y}{\log^{3} y}?$$

Comment: please specify the quantifiers for $x, y$, the words "pick up" and "simultaneously" seem contradictory for me

Comment: The estimate in your question implies that the numbers $\{\frac{x}{d}\}$ would be biased to be very close to zero, that is
$$
\left\{\frac{x}{d}\right\} \leq \frac{1}{(\log y)^3}
$$
for many $d$, but there is (as far as I know) absolutely no reason to believe this to be the case, and least when $y$ is smaller than $x^{1/2-\varepsilon}$, say.